# Tkinter - Positioning of Toplevel() window not as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently playing around with programming some GUI using `tkinter` and struggle now with properly setting the position of a child window created by `tk.Toplevel()`

What I want to achieve is to have my new window positioned at the upper right corner of the main window. So I calculated the target position by using `winfo` of the root window but even if the values seem to be correct at the first place, the y-position always has an offset after setting these values

A small example:

```
import tkinter as tk

def create_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    root.update()
    x = root.winfo_x() + root.winfo_width()
    y = root.winfo_y()

    print ("winfo_x:\t\t" + str(root.winfo_x()))
    print ("winfo_y:\t\t" + str(root.winfo_y()))
    print ("winfo_w:\t\t" + str(root.winfo_width()))
    print ("winfo_h:\t\t" + str(root.winfo_height()))
    print ("target x:\t\t" + str(x))
    print ("target y:\t\t" + str(y) + "\n")

    window.geometry("+%d+%d" % (x,y))
    window.update()

    print ("actual x:\t\t" + str(window.winfo_x()))
    print ("actual y:\t\t" + str(window.winfo_y()))


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
button = tk.Button(root, text="create window", command=create_window)
button.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```

The output e.g. is:

```
winfo_x:        722
winfo_y:        215
winfo_w:        800
winfo_h:        600
target x:       1522
target y:       215

actual x:       1522
actual y:       245
```

So when setting the position using `geometry()` it seems to automatically offset the `y` pos by the title bar height.

Am I missing something here or do I really need to negate this offset manually? But as I understand `winfo` should return the position of the window's border and not of its viewable area

**Edit**

This problem only occurs on my Ubuntu-18.04 virtual machine - on the windows 7 host (`python 3.8.0`) it works as intended.
I tried `python3.8` and `python3.6.9` both with `tkinter 8.6`

Comment: Your code works fine (no offset on `actual y`) in my Windows 10 running Python 3.8.1.

Comment: @acw1668 Good point, on my windows host (Python 3.8.0) it also works, but on my Ubuntu-VM (also Python 3.8.0) it doesn't

Comment: It works in my Ubuntu 18.04 (Windows Subsystem for Linux) running Python 3.6.9.

Comment: my vm also runs Ubuntu-18.04 and python with `tkinter` 8.6

Comment: I think it is the different behaviours between the window manager in Windows and Linux that you cannot resolve.

Comment: @acw1668 But your Ubuntu also seems to behave differently to mine in this concern

Comment: I have tried in a Ubuntu 16.04 VM and has the same issue.  My Ubuntu 18.04 is WSL and using VcXsrv X Server in Windows.

Comment: I see - thanks for checking this out